# Auto-update Date in R (always query yesterday)

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown, tidyverse

I usually read these data from a local system while I manually change the date,
for example, today's date is the 2nd of November which is like this format in the link below (2021_11_02), so what I do is create a report for a day before which is the 1st of November 2021 (2021_11_01)

I manually update this date before I can create the report

now I want to schedule automation that will run the report by itself

how do I write a code in r that will automatically update the date a day -1 which is yesterday in the report or in anywhere required in the script?

is there a way r can auto-update date by minus 1 (always use yesterday date)

or

how to instruct R to automatically use a day minus one date in any script that has a date

please see the sample link from the local machine

```
DWReport_2021_11_01 <-read_csv("C:/Users/Guest 1/Downloads/DWReport_2021-11-01.csv")
DWReport_2021_11_01_1_ <-read_csv("C:/Users/Guest 1/Downloads/DWReport_2021-11-01 (1).csv")
match_report<-rbind(DWReport_2021_11_01,DWReport_2021_11_01_1_)
```

also, I want to get something to always change the date as a day minus one which a day before whenever I'm querying the database
see sample script below

```
tbl(connect, "accotdebits")%>%
  filter(dates > "1633046400" & dates < "1633910399" &
           tranx_status == "Successfull")%>%
                  collect()
```

two questions one to read a day minus one from my local machine
two to auto-update date to a day minus one yesterday whenever its querying the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Sys.Date() to get today's date. You can subtract a day simply we with minus 1.

```
yesterday <- Sys.Date()  - 1
yesterday_formatted <- format( yesterday, "%Y_%m_%d")
```

You can then use those values in your code

```
temp <- read_csv( paste0("C:/users/guest/downloads/DWReport_", yesterday,".csv")

assign(paste0("DWReport_", yesterday_formatted), temp)
```

Your final query.. where you are querying the database... Unusual not to be passing a date to the database?  What flavour SQL is this?   Is this simply a Unix timestamp?

If you convert the date to a POSIXct and then a numeric you can get a timestamp. You may need to add the HH mm manually...

```
yesterday_numeric <- as.numeric( as.POSIXct( format (yesterday, "%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00")))
tbl(connect, "accotdebits")%>%
  filter(dates > yesterday_numeric & dates < (yesterday_numeric+(24*60*60)) &
           tranx_status == "Successfull")%>%
                  collect()
```